# Problem with xServer, Unity and xfce are not working. Problem with driver

Tags: drivers, unity, nvidia, lightdm, xserver

I restarted my computer a couple a days ago and since then I am only able to see the lightdm. everytime I login to unity it fails and I end up back at the lightdm login screen. If I login choosing xfce I get a blank screen and have to reboot.

I already tried to reinstall unity, yet it seems to be a problem with the xServer. If I try to start the xserver in a new tty I get an immediate black screen and have to reboot.

Trying to reinstall the nvidia driver package did not do anything.

I am running Ubuntu 17.04. on a Fujitsu Celsius with a Nvidia Quadro M2000 graka any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be the .XAuthority file which belonged to root (due to installation of a driver as root). I chmod'ed the file and everything was working like a breeze -)

To learn something in general, use `journalctl` to debug.